# how to get title when table has type column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have a simple site model with single table inheritance `sites(id, type, title, address)` where type can be "Home" or "office".  When we were on Rails 2.3.5 we could do `Site.last.title` and it would give the title.  However, on Rails 3.2.6, when we do `Site.last.title` it give us the value as the type column instead.

Is it possible to get the value of the title instead of the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the newest value of a table, It is better to find it by `created_at` column. By default, using `Site.last`, Rails will search by primary key (`ID`), which is fine most of the time. However, if for any reason you need to change an `ID` on an existing record, your SQL will not return what you expect.

So, it is better to do something like:

```
Site.order("created_at").last.title
```

Regarding the problem you are facing, I think the problem is related to the `type` and not the `title`. Anyway, I recommend you to set the newest `site` in your controller and then call it in your view.

```
#controller
@site=Site.order("created_at").last

#view
@site.title
```

I hope it helps...